# Alert on Windows startup

Tags: windows, windows-8, environment-variables

I get a weird alert on windows startup and have no clue where it is from,
but I have a feeling it has to do something with environment variables. I did some research, but couldn't find a thing.

I am using: **Windows 8 Pro x64**

This is the alert I get:

[image]

I would really appreciate some help as its annoying the s... out of me, cuzz I don't know it's origin. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** After going throuh startups i found Jenkins in there and I remember that I played with the installation a bit coouple days ago. Uninstalled it retsarted PC no more alert. Tnx for help everyone all of you get an upvote!

Comment: The one thing I can say for certain is that this prompt isn't generated by Windows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find everything that runs at startup with the Microsoft/SystemInternals tool "Autoruns". The [info page is here.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902)

Answer (score 4):

Leave the prompt open and then open the Windows 8 Task Manager as Administrator and analyze carefully all the processes.

But i guess some program was not installed properly and that is why you are getting the alert. Is your date and time set correctly ? Try changing your date and time to a random date and time and then set it correctly and restart your computer.